# use of if-statement in build.xml giving error

Tags: if-statement, jenkins, build.xml

Iam running a project through jenkins but iam getting the errors as

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/K2_Learning_Build/build.xml:130: The following error occurred while      
executing this line:

/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/K2_Learning_Build/IgnitorACE/build.xml:251: Element type "if" must be  
followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

I have used if condition in my build.xml as follows at line 251

```
<if ${INSTITUTE_NAME} == "K2_Learning">
<property name = "https.start" value='android:htps=\"' />
<replaceregexp file="../BuildConfig/src/com/edutor/build/${TYPE}.java"  match="public static     
 final String NAVIGATION_MENU_ITEMS[] = (.*)"  replace="public static final String 
 NAVIGATION_MENU_ITEMS[] = ${MENU_LIST_ITEMS};" />    
</if>
<else>
<echo>INSTITUTE_Name: ${INSTITUTE_NAME}</echo>
</else>
```

Please suggest the solution...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you can't use `if` like this... Try:

```
<if>
    <contains string="${INSTITUTE_NAME}" substring="K2_Learning" />
    <then>
        ...
    </then>
</if>
```

See also spec and examples at SF: [ant-contrib if spec](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I used the above syntax but now getting the new error as follows ...  /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/K2_Learning_Build/IgnitorACE/build.xml:251: if doesn't support the nested "contains" element.

Comment: Which version of ant are you using? From the link I posted `This task is heavily based on the Condition framework that can be found in Ant 1.4 and later, therefore it cannot be used inconjunction with versions of Ant prior to 1.4. Due to numeruos bugs in Ant 1.4(.1) that affect this task, we recommend to use Ant 1.5 or later.`.

Comment: Also, you could do the same thing with pure ant [conditions](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html). Have a read and play.